# Multiple statements in an induction argument

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $0 < a_1 < b_1$ and we define recurrences:

$$a_{n + 1} = \sqrt{a_n b_n}$$

and

$$b_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{2} \left( a_n + b_n \right)$$

I want to prove that both sequences converge by the monotone sequence theorem.

Is there a problem in proving by induction that $a_n \leq b_n$, $a_{n} \leq a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n} \geq b_{n + 1}$ all at the same time?

My propose proof using the induction hypothesis is:

$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n b_n} \leq \frac{1}{2} (a_n + b_n) = b_{n+1}$$

$$a_{n + 2} = \sqrt{a_{n + 1} b_{n + 1}} \geq \sqrt{a_{n + 1}^2} = a_{n + 1}$$

$$b_{n + 2} = \frac{1}{2} (a_{n + 1} + b_{n+1}) \leq \frac{1}{2} (b_{n + 1} + b_{n+1}) = b_{n + 1}$$

Now that I'm checking the question I have observed that for $a_n \leq b_n$ I don't need to use induction. But I have the doubt if with induction you can have multiple statements and use induction to prove them at the same time.

Comment: show that for all $a_n,b_n$ that $a_n<a_{n+1}<b_{n+1} < b_n$  Then $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence bounded above by $b_0$ and $\{b_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by $a_0.$  And sequences that are montonic and bounded converge.

Comment: "But I have the doubt if with induction you can have multiple statements and use induction to prove them at the same time": Yes you can. But here, it is more elegant to prove directly $a_n\le b_n$ without induction, and then the rest using induction.

Comment: You can; let the statement to be proven be "$(a_n\le b_n) \land(a_n\le a_{n+1})\land (b_n\ge b_{n+1})$".

Comment: "But I have the doubt if with induction you can have multiple statements and use induction to prove them at the same time."  Of course you can! (And you did.  Successfully.)